# Can an union's destructor be trivial?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, unions

Given the following code:

```
struct Bar {
    Bar() { }
    ~Bar() { }
};

struct FooBase {
    // No virtual destructor
};

struct Foo : FooBase {
    Foo() : bar{} { }

    union {
        Bar bar;
    };
};

int main() {
    FooBase *p = new Foo;
    static_cast<Foo *>(p)->bar.~Bar();
    delete p;
}
```

I wish to detach `Foo::bar`'s lifetime from its enclosing `Foo`.
As far as I know, `delete p;` is well-defined if and only if `Foo`'s destructor is trivial.
Since `Foo` only contains an union, and is not supposed to destruct its `bar` itself, it looks like it is the case: informally speaking, that destructor does nothing.

But is this code actually well-defined according to the standard?

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/689ac09526e80c48)

Comment: 1.) An unnamed union with just one member variable is odd. 2.) If you are unsure then it is very likely UB. I would question your assumtion that `delete p` is well defined here.

Comment: @knivil I *am* questioning whether it's well-defined ;)

Comment: Ah ,,, I though you ask about the other odd things like `Foo`s destructor or assignment to a base class pointer without being polymorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `[expr.delete]` for me doesn't support your claim that "*`delete p;` is well-defined if and only if Foo's destructor is trivial*".

> In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Since the static type is `FooBase` whereas the dynamic type is `Foo`, I'd expect that to be UB.

Furthermore, (even in case this is not UB) I think that the destructor of `Foo` isn't trivial.

> [class.union]
>
> A union-like class is a union or a class that has an anonymous union as a direct member. A union-like `class X` has a set of variant members. If `X` is a union its variant members are the non-static data members; otherwise, its variant members are the non-static data members of all anonymous unions that are members of `X`.

Thus `Foo` is a union-like class with `bar` (of type `Bar` which has a non-trivial destructor) being a variant member.

> [class.dtor]
>
> 4) If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted [...].
>
> 5) A defaulted destructor for a `class X` is defined as deleted if
>
> - `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial destructor [...].

Therefore, I think that the implicitly defaulted destructor of `Foo` should be defined as deleted and must be user-provided.

(Declare `Foo q;` and see the compilation fail.)

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if
>
> - [...] for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial destructor.

I'd exepect that clause to extend to variant members as well since it doesn't say "non-variant data members".

---

You **could** have a virtual destructor in `FooBase` and then implement `~Foo()` without including `bar.~bar();` where it would be possible to destroy `bar` in advance without it being destructed again in `~Foo()`.

I'd however strongly advise against it since you'd have to somehow call `~bar` for every static or dynamic `Foo` before it goes out of scope.

Comment: VS2015: warning C4624: 'Foo': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted

Comment: [g++ 6.3:  error: use of deleted function `Foo::~Foo()`](http://ideone.com/NFkzPf)

Comment: Is the destructor of `Foo` used if I destroy it through a base class pointer?

Comment: @knivil: If the base class doesn't have a virtual destructor it is UB. The implementation may or may not use the destructor of `Foo`.